# How is R.drawable able to resolve R.drawable.sample_2, etc?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gridview Tutorial problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276260/gridview-tutorial-problems)

In the android grid view tutorial, they use `R.drawable.sample_0`, `R.drawable.sample_1`, `R.drawable.sample_2`, etc.

These properties are not defined in `R.drawable`. How does java resolve this without errors?

Comment: sample_0 ,sample_1,sample_2 are not properties these are images that has been used be the author who wrote tutorial
add any 3 images you lie it will be resloved

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276260/gridview-tutorial-problems. The same question, hope it helps :)

Comment: Usman, I know that they are images, but still, how does java know not to complain? If I made an empty class, and called some random property, how doe sit know how to resolve it? I guess this is more of a java question than android.

Comment: You have to import images into the res/drawable folder (using copy and paste) named sample_0(.jpg/png), sample_1, sample_2, etc

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are defined "on the fly" any time you compile your project. Go and inspect your "gen/[package]/R.java" autogenerated file, you will see something similar to:

```
public final class R {
    public static final class drawable {
        public static final int sample_0=0x7f020000;
        public static final int sample_1=0x7f020001;
        public static final int sample_2=0x7f020002;
    }
}
```

So, when using `R.drawable.sample_0` we are just making use of nested static declarations inside R class.