# What is the shortcut to Auto import all in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, auto-import

Is there any way of auto importing in Android Studio. Something like the auto-import feature that **Eclipse** has when you use the keybinding: **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>** in **Android Studio**?

Currently I have only found <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, which ask each individual thing, and I keep having to use the keybinding <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to accept.

###### Is there any way I can speed things up?

Comment: what do you wanna import?

Comment: Something like organize import (classes) in Eclipse.

Comment: but I'm looking for an keyboard shortcut for Android Studio.

Comment: create your own https://code.google.com/p/android-keyboard-switcher/source/browse/src/ru/gelin/android/keyboard/Shortcut.java?spec=svnbf9e819152011d381a1d109fd074c5659bbe0125&r=bf9e819152011d381a1d109fd074c5659bbe0125

Comment: How a developer platform (on PC) is related to that?

Comment: "organise imports on the fly" is what you want, if you opened settings and in the search box type 'import' you would have found it

Comment: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html

Comment: use File -> Settings -> Editor ->*General*-> Auto Import -> Java  for Android Studio 1.2 beta 3

Comment: Press Alt + Shift + M

Comment: On macOS, press `Ctrl+Alt+O`

Answer (score 1317, accepted):

For Windows/Linux, you can go to `File` -> `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `General` -> `Auto Import` -> `Java` and make the following changes:

- change `Insert imports on paste` value to `All`
- mark`Add unambigious imports on the fly` option as checked

On a Mac, do the same thing in `Android Studio` -> `Preferences`

[image]

After this, all unambiguous imports will be added automatically.

Comment: i am not find any Setting option in File Tab, it have option import/export/ and otherSettings that also don't have any Editor Option...any suggestion.

Comment: Use Preferences under the Android Studio menu.

Comment: Just what I was looking for!  The Studio/IDEA, GNOME and Emacs keybindings overlap a good bit.  Ctrl+Alt+S maps to GNOME "Toggle Shaded State" - which quickly rolls up/down a window.  Disable GNOME keybinding to allow this keybinding to work in the studio window.

Comment: If you do this, there's a bug in Android Studio 0.4.3 and earlier where it can be aggressive about replacing "R.<resource id name>" with "android.R.<resource id name>" if there's an error that prevents R.java from being automatically generated. To avoid problems, you should add "android.R" to the "Exclude from Import and Completion" list; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102497/why-did-android-studio-change-all-my-references-from-r-to-android-r?noredirect=1#comment31771944_21102497

Comment: While i understand this is the correct and handy way along with using the Ctrl+Alt+O to optimize them... It seems mine will not update or allow the Auto Import to work when pasting.. Only rarely did it ask me to Import...damn bugs

Comment: They really need a shortcut for this, like Eclipse.  I don't want to keep this setting on all the time, but sometimes I really need it.  For example, when I commented / uncommented a bunch of code.

Comment: I did this but you are still prompted to hit Alt-Enter on every class to import it. Not exactly "auto import".

Comment: It works for me, if you use that option you must use Ctrl+Alt+O instead of Alt+Intro, all it will try to import everything

Comment: Too bad, I can only +1 :(

Comment: does it optimize imports automatically ? because I need to do Command + Alt + O every time even with these options selected.

Comment: Not really a big difference.Specially the first part is nonesense.You can let it ask you and then import why put it on all?

Comment: there is no ALL option in "Insert imports on paste" in Android studio Arctic Fox

Answer (score 89):

#### These are the shortcuts used in Android studio

Go to class <kbd>CTRL + N</kbd>
Go to file <kbd>CTRL + Shift + N</kbd>
Navigate open tabs <kbd>ALT + Left-Arrow</kbd>; <kbd>ALT + Right-Arrow</kbd>
Look up recent files <kbd>CTRL + E</kbd>
Go to line <kbd>CTRL + G</kbd>
Navigate to last edit location <kbd>CTRL + SHIFT + BACKSPACE</kbd>
Go to declaration <kbd>CTRL + B</kbd>
Go to implementation <kbd>CTRL + ALT + B</kbd>
Go to source <kbd>F4</kbd>
Go to super Class <kbd>CTRL + U</kbd>
Show Call hierarchy <kbd>CTRL + ALT + H</kbd>
Search in path/project <kbd>CTRL + SHIFT + F</kbd>

#### Programming Shortcuts:-

Reformat code <kbd>CTRL + ALT + L</kbd>
Optimize imports <kbd>CTRL + ALT + O</kbd>
Code Completion <kbd>CTRL + SPACE</kbd>
Issue quick fix <kbd>ALT + ENTER</kbd>
Surround code block <kbd>CTRL + ALT + T</kbd>
Rename and Refractor <kbd>Shift + F6</kbd>
Line Comment or Uncomment <kbd>CTRL + /</kbd>
Block Comment or Uncomment <kbd>CTRL + SHIFT + /</kbd>
Go to previous/next method <kbd>ALT + UP/DOWN</kbd>
Show parameters for method <kbd>CTRL + P</kbd>
Quick documentation lookup <kbd>CTRL + Q</kbd>
Delete a line <kbd>CTRL + Y</kbd>
View declaration in layout <kbd>CTRL + B</kbd>

For more info visit [Things worked in Android](http://androideasythings.blogspot.in/2015/01/android-studio-shortcuts-needful.html)

Comment: That is nice, but doesn't answer OP's question.

Comment: CTRL + ALT + L not working in Ubuntu instead its locks down the display.

Answer (score 87):

By changing the keymaps settings you can use the same keyboard short cuts as in Eclipse (Or your favourite IDE)

**File -> Settings -> KeyMap**

**Android Studio -> Preferences -> KeyMap** (Mac)

Change keymaps settings to eclipse so that you can use the short cut keys like in eclipse. For those who just want to change this one setting, it is

**Main Menu -> Code -> Optimize Imports...**

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific item in Intelij that is equivalent to ctrl shift O in eclipse?  I am not finding it.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+O for android studio in Mac

Comment: *This* answer is what I was after.

Comment: This answer is incorrect! The question is: is there a way to Auto Import? Your answer makes Android Studio to eliminate unused imports. The author wants to auto import a class like `com.company.bean.MyBean` automatically, when he writes `MyBean bean = new MyBean();`

Answer (score 27):

> Android Studio --> Preferences --> Editors --> General --> Auto Import

- Checked **Optimize imports on the fly** option
- Checked to **Add unambiguous imports on the fly** option
- Click Apply and OK button.

Comment: Preferences --> Editor --> General --> Auto Import

Answer (score 14):

Note that in my Android Studio 1.4, Auto Import now under General

> (Android Studio --> Preferences --> Editors --> General --> Auto
>   Import)

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can make short cut key for missing import in android studio which you like

1. Click on file Menu
2. Click on Settting
3. click on key map
4. Search for "auto-import"
5. double click on auto import and select add keyboard short cut key
6. that's all

[image]

[image]

[image]

> Note: You can import single missing import using alt+enter which shown in pop up

[image]

Answer (score 7):

On Windows, highlight the code that has classes which need to be resolved and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: This is what I was looking for, are there any other similar options to do this on the particular problem item rather than the class?

Answer (score 5):

> Go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> Auto Import -> Java and make the
>   below things:

Select Insert imports on paste value to All

Do tick mark on Add unambigious imports on the fly option and "Optimize imports on the fly*

Answer (score 5):

File > Settings > Editor > General >Auto Import (Mac: Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > General >Auto Import).

Select all check boxes and set Insert imports on paste to All. Unambiguous imports are now added automatically to your files.

[Reference](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-practicals/content/en/Unit%201/11_p_hello_world.html)

Answer (score 3):

For Linux (Ubuntu 14.04), you can go to

**File -> Settings -> Editor -> Auto Import**

**check all** the boxes and insert all imports on paste.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the Latest Version of Android Studio, the options for Auto-Import is enabled by default, so kudos no need to worry about that.

On Windows:
If for some reasons auto-import is not enable you can go to settings by typing shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

In the Search term just type 'Auto-Import' and then select 'Add unambiguous Imports on the fly' and click Ok.

That's it. You are Done.
[SnapShot of Auto_import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGF4v.png)

Answer (score 2):

as I have found on [kotlin training from google developers](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-create-dice-roller-app-with-button?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-kotlin-four%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-training-create-dice-roller-app-with-button#3), on android studio 4.2.2, On macOS, open the settings by going to **File > New Project Settings > Preferences for New Projects...** Expand **Other Settings > Auto Import**. In the Java and Kotlin sections, make sure **Add unambiguous imports on the fly** and **Optimize imports on the fly** **(for current project)** are checked. Note that there are two checkboxes in each section. Save the changes and close settings by pressing **OK**.

[image]

In Windows, open the settings by going to **File > Settings > Editor > General > Auto Import**. In the **Java** and **Kotlin** sections, make sure **Add unambiguous imports on the fly** and **Optimize imports on the fly (for current project)** are checked. Note that there are two checkboxes in each section. Save the changes and close settings by pressing **OK**.

[image]

The **unambiguous imports** settings tell Android Studio to automatically add an import statement, as long as it can determine which one to use. The **optimize imports** settings tell Android Studio to remove any imports that aren't being used by your code.