# Why did Android Studio change all my references from R to android.R?

Tags: android, android-studio, r.java-file

I made an error in an Android layout file (forgot the `dp` in my dimension), and upon rebuilding, Android Studio replaced all of my references to `R.java` (which, because of the erroneous build, did not generate) with `android.R.java`. Is this *normal* behavior? How do I disable this? Is this caused by allowing auto-imports?

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Do you have a reproducible test case? If so we can file it, and maybe you can get some help on the question here.

Comment: @ScottBarta I was able to replicate the bug, so made the report here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64802&thanks=64802&ts=1389711338

Comment: @ScottBarta did this get fixed in the latest build (0.5.0 or 0.5.1)?

Comment: No, the bug is still open. I don't have an ETA.

Comment: This bug is now fixed in the current release of Android Studio (confirmed about 25 minutes ago).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's happening is that the error in your XML file is preventing your project's **R.java** from being generated during the build, and the IDE is seeing that your `R` references in the code could now unambiguously autocomplete to `android.R`, and the **Add unambiguous imports on the fly** setting is going ahead and doing that. Problem is, `android.R` is the wrong import, when it really should wait for **R.java** to resolve.

If you want to leave **Add unambiguous imports on the fly** set, please add `android.R` to the **Exclude from Import and Completion** list in **Preferences** > **Editor** > **Auto Import** as shown here:

[image: Screen shot of the Editor > Auto Import preferences dialog]

Comment: Nice! Thanks for getting back so fast.

Comment: Thanks for the diagnostic work on it. Without your step in the bug setting up imports a la http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615038/what-is-the-shortcut-to-auto-import-all-in-android-studio, I would have never realized what was going on.