# writing extended class methods in android Studio

Tags: android, methods

Just migrating Eclipse to Android Studio, and struggling a lot without knowing much shortcuts and import the extended class methods such as "Right Click-> Source->Override/Implement Methods" then we implement methods. Here I found no Source option. How may I include those methods. plz help me to get this quickly, as now I'm typing them .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android Studio the menu you're looking for is `Code`. You then can select what types of methods you need generated.

Comment: how can I import the Classes like Activity, ActionBarActivity?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615038/what-is-the-shortcut-to-auto-import-all-in-android-studio).