# Cannot resolve symbol 'Activity' after upgrading android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I upgraded android studio from the precious version to beta 0.8.6 but now Activity class is not recognized. Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615038/what-is-the-shortcut-to-auto-import-all-in-android-studio  Check this