# Error to initialize the parse.com code in Android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm beginner  with Java/Android and Parse. Today i need your help . I don't know what i'm doing wrong. Look to my picture

[image]

My .jar file is in "Lib" , but i'm receiving the red lines in my project. 
Also ,how can you see in Parse.initialize seems that this is not recognized.

Comment: Clear and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should import classes

add this import statement to your codes

```
import com.parse.Parse;
```

and import every class you need 
you can also import all classes

```
 import com.parse.blablabla.....;
```

and if you have added `.jar` files you can fix imports in android studio .[check this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615038/what-is-the-shortcut-to-auto-import-all-in-android-studio)

follow these steps

`1)` add parse libs to your project.

`2)`clean your project

`3)` add import statement

```
import com.parse.Parse;
```

you can see i have no error after i did those steps

this is my project no errors

[image]

Comment: @Leogreen what? yesterday ?

Comment: Yesterday I did it :  import com.parse.Parse;   I added this but still got an error in runtime i did like in parse.com tutorial to android . you can see in picture above

Comment: yes ,but i did it before ,after i tried other thing . lol But my .jar file is in the right place?

Comment: ok very thanks! Thanks for your time! Tonight i'll try again ,,and i tell you about!

Comment: Wow helped me a lot. Thanks!! Yes now ,i have no more the red lines. is everything okay. But when i try to do this tutorial(parse oficial)  https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/new  i don't have sucess ( nothing good ,nothing wrong).

Comment: And i'm receiving this:  error: cannot access Task class file for bolts.Task not found .So , i added bolts.jar https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/103204235/Captura%20de%20tela%202014-11-04%2022.31.25.png   But is different of your picture.And i still have the same error.

Comment: with:  dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('src/libs/Parse-1.7.1.jar')
    compile files('src/libs/bolts-android-1.1.3') i have no problem .. but i still have no sucess. Why? my app run but i don't receive results in Parse.com >>>> 0 req. this month :(

Comment: @Leogreen i have no experience with parse.com..so i can't figure-out your rest of errors.anyway you don't need to aadd compile files('src/libs/Parse-1.7.1.jar') since  { compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) compiles all jars in lib.