# Red parse in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am trying to make a simple app for a kickboxing webpage. I'm new to this, so pardon my noob question.  (yes, I have searched for days for fix)

First, I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2fRVvGkRJE8
I got it running, but every click on links made a browser popup. so, in the comments of the video, the answer to fix, was:

## **FIX**

Make application WebView not redirect to the web browser when clicked on a link, we need to add WebViewClient class and override its method.
Add the code below to your WebView application:

```
import android.webkit.WebView; //import WebView class
import android.webkit.WebViewClient; //import WebViewClient class

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView); 
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        view.loadUrl("http://teknorial.com");
    }

   private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
       @Override
        public  boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url ){
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**Fix End**

Well, I tried a lot of times to input this, but got no-go... I did not understand where, or how to put this into the script. I tried like thousand ways. (yes, and updated every string)

so, I found another tutorial, a bad english-speaking rice-and-curry dude.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LzlNP9nS6fo  --> one of three in this tutorial.

I got all working, But, in the second video, he explains how to Override the linkinbrowser-outside-app function..  I got everything right but one thing.. i get this red parse string, and cannot fix it in any way...  I think it has something with the versions I'm working with to do, but have no clue..

I followed the advice from your forum here:
[Error to initialize the parse.com code in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735259/error-to-initialize-the-parse-com-code-in-android)

but the "import com.parse.Parse;" showed inactive..  -yes, I'm noob...

see the attachments for screenshot of my problem.  I think maybe I have to  change a version string of some-kind of IDE or some other mod, I read somewhere... but have no clue..  the SDK picture shows everything I installed, every option in every folder is installed..

Thanks for all replies :-)

Boiker

*I tried to post 3 images of my problem (wich had made any replies easier and maybe more accurate answers, but I needed 10 reputations to do that :-( )

--

Comment: So what are you asking?

Comment: hmm maybe a checklist for red parsing, or something i can begin to figure out how to fix a red string in parsing..   or maybe a step-by-step list on the fix from the video...  :-/  And thx for worlds fastest answer :-)