# Android Studio import shortcuts from Eclipse

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

From someone who has used Eclipse for awhile I Prefer keeping the same shortcuts in Android studio. Is it possible to import shortcuts in Android Studio from Eclipse ?

Comment: Try this. So that u can configure your shortcuts jus like your favorite IDE (Eclipse..) http://stackoverflow.com/a/25419358/3020568

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android studio allows you to use the Eclipse default shortcuts. If you go to Settings -> Keymap then you can chose from a selection of preset mappings in a dropdown menu. One of the options is Eclipse.