# How to Optimize Imports on All Files in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, import, code-formatting

How do I `Optimize Imports` on a whole folder or project?

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-O removes unused imports. I am not aware of a bulk add-all-missing-imports option being mapped to a key combination, though it is conceivable that you could set one up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the shortcut to Auto import all in Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615038/what-is-the-shortcut-to-auto-import-all-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Android Studio is still based off of Eclipse, try

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

Which should be organize / optimize imports.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Runs the auto code formatter.

Comment: Android Studio was never based off of Eclipse. It is based off of JetBrains' IntelliJ IDEA. You may be thinking of the old ADT Plugin for Eclipse, the original IDE support from Google.

Answer (score 10):

To optimize imports on the whole project, choose the folder/project you want from the project pane, then press:

- <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd><kbd>`Alt`</kbd><kbd>`O`</kbd> on Windows
- <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd><kbd>`Option`</kbd><kbd>`O`</kbd> on Mac

`Optimize Imports` is also available from the right-click menu on projects, folders, files, etc in the project pane.

[image]

Comment: This is it! See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51833539/how-to-delete-all-unused-imports-from-current-project-in-intellij-idea

Answer (score 2):

try the Optimize imports (Option + Ctr + O) option in android studio

go to Preferences --> Keymap -- > and look for "Optimize imports" to find the right shortcut