# How to delete all unused imports from current project in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have been using `Intellij Idea` for quite some time now. I have a few questions though. Is there a way to **delete all unused imports from all files in the current project**?

I know that I can choose menu item `Code` > `Optimize Imports` (`CTRL + ALT + O`) to organize imports in individual files but since the application that I am working on has hundreds of files, this process does not make any sense. If there is no way of doing this, can I create a macro for this? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: The question really is: Why wasn't that done as the files were created/edited? Unused imports should have shown as a warning, and anyone checking in code with warnings needs to be penalized, e.g. by forcing them to do this one file at a time.

Comment: @Andreas I do agree with you. But you see, for old applications, I guess the developers went sloppy with the approach. However, for all the new applications that we are developing, we make sure that the rules are set in `Sonar Cube`

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Click the project folder, then enter <kbd>CTRL + ALT + O</kbd>. It will handle all files under the folder:

[image]

Comment: I tried this and it worked (I guess). Does this process notify somewhere the number of imports that were deleted?

Comment: @Prashant I do not think it will. May be you can use the version control tool, such as Git, to see the differences.

Comment: Ah! Nice idea. Thanks.

Comment: This changes every file in your project, though.  Don't do this unless you want a massive commit even though nothing was really changed in the files (except for white space).