# Android Gradle build error Need to connect with database

Tags: android, androidhttpclient, android-json

Do i need to add any jar file. or need to and any dependencies

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
         minifyEnabled false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    compile   'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.  client:4.1.2'
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3"
 }
```

And it displays this error in console:

> Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5 is ignored    for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
>   In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
>
> Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5 is ignored   for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by   Android.
>   In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the  class packages

Answer (score 0):

On the contrary, you need to remove a dependency. The warning message is telling you that you're trying to import a dependency that's already included in Android. So you might not need the line

`compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5' #Try removing this line`

Try removing it and see if the app works correctly. If it doesn't and you still need to import HttpClient, please refer to [this page](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/android-port.html) (it's posted just a few days go by apache.org, it doesn't get any more official than that).

The link above basically tells you that you should use:

> Apache HttpClient 4.3 port for Android when targeting Android API 22 and older

```
dependencies {
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
}
```

or

> Apache HttpClient packages for Android [maintained by Marek Sebera](https://github.com/smarek/httpclient-android/wiki/Project-Introduction) when targeting Android API 23 and newer

```
dependencies {
compile group: 'cz.msebera.android' , name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.1'
}
```

Comment: It shows error you are using unsused imports  import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

Comment: Is it an error or a warning? If it's an error, it has a red color. But if it's a warning, it should have a yellow color.
Also, try auto importing your libraries as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615038/what-is-the-shortcut-to-auto-import-all-in-android-studio)