# What is the way to enable the auto-import in android studio ? [windows]

Tags: android, android-studio, import, keyevent

Whenever i need to import every time i need to use `Alt+Enter`. what is the way to enable **auto-import in android studio** ? (in windows)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the shortcut to Auto import all in Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615038/what-is-the-shortcut-to-auto-import-all-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It is similar case for windows and osx so there will be no change.**

In android studio go to

> file  --> setting --> auto-import --> check all options

like

- **show auto-import**
- **Optimize imports on the fly** option
- **Add unambiguous imports on the fly** option

thats it.

As mentioned in comment above check link [What is the shortcut to Auto import all in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615038/what-is-the-shortcut-to-auto-import-all-in-android-studio)