# Class does auto not import Android Studio

Tags: android, observable, android-databinding

Why [BR class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BaseObservable) **(Android data-binding auto generated class for bindable fields)** in android does not auto import like another classes, `alt + enter` does not work for this class?

When i write `notifyPropertyChanged(BR.someField);` for any field, i have to manually import that class with full package name.

**Note** All other classes can be imported automatically but only this **BR** class is not importing.

Even if turned on `file --> setting --> auto-import --> check all options`

Comment: try this @khemraj
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36144299/what-is-the-way-to-enable-the-auto-import-in-android-studio-windows

Comment: Not useful for me

Comment: I've seen two causes for this. First, resources need to be compiled before BR class is available.  So, if there are errors in the resources or you recently made a change and it is not compiled, the class won't be available for import.  Second, BR can exist in multiple packages. The ambiguity seems to confuse it but can sometimes work around by explicitly typing the full path (e.g. `com.mypackage.BR`).

Comment: Yes it works with typing full path, but it should behave like other classes, just type BR and import by alt + enter. Lets see android improve it.