# Import classes automatically without opening class in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I used "replace structurally" to bulk add  **Locale.ENGLISH** in SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat,Locale.ENGLISH) , now I have to import java.util.Locale to all modified classes , Is there is a way to bulk import to all classes without having to open each class and pressing alt + enter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615038/what-is-the-shortcut-to-auto-import-all-in-android-studio

Comment: Nope, This one will autoimport on the fly , which is NOW a default option in Android Studio ,  the case am talking about is when you modify a class without even opening it , I need some command that will check all the missing imports all over the project and add them , without me having to get into each class to trigger the auto import.