# Retrofit cannot find symbol

Tags: android, retrofit

> ```
>  ckage com.netvariant.helloworld;
>   import retrofit.Callback;
>   import retrofit.http.GET;
>   import retrofit.http.Query;
>   import retrofit.Call;
>  public interface StackOverflowAPI {
> @GET("/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow")
> Call<StackOverflowQuestions> loadQuestions(@Query("tagged") String tags);}
> ```

I have included in my gradle file
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'

Whats the issue?

Comment: Use `import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;...` instead. About auto import, pls read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615038/what-is-the-shortcut-to-auto-import-all-in-android-studio

Answer (score 2):

From Retrofit 2.0.* the directy is renamed from retrofit to retrofit2 you can find it here.
[updated directory path](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2)