# Missing import after semicolon (Android studio 2.1)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.1

When i am writing line: `import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;` in the android studio,

The above line gets disappear as soon as i hit enter after the semicolon.

Could it be due to line: `import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;`

And when the `TextView` import line disappears,also there is no + sign hence there is definitely no line folding. 
Please propose some solution to help me as I couldn't find any solution online. Is frustrating.

Comment: Take a look at [Auto import](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16615038/5151575)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Go to Settings > Editor > General > Auto Import**

**Uncheck Optimize import on the Fly**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

to import any class you should use like this

```
import root.subroot.classname;
```

here you are making a mistake `import.name;`

change

> import.android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;

to

> `import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;`

Comment: Hi Sadiq, thanks for the correction, unfortunately, it appears to be a typo in my questions. The problem still prevails....any solution for me?

Comment: check my new answer! couldn't add a picture here!

Answer (score 0):

Its because you haven't used any object of bluetooth adapter instatiate a object of that class and it will automatically be visible... fading of import statement means its redundant

Comment: Hi, how to add the object of the class. It appears that everything is reduncant because nothing can be added. After semicolon everything disappears.