# Using Spinner in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, mobile

### While using `spinner` in `fragment` i am getting these errors ##

```
//my fragments code

    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

    import static android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item;

    public class lang_spinner extends Fragment{
        Spinner source_lang;
        Spinner target_lang;
        String array_sourcelang[];
        String array_targetlang[];
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.lang_spinner, container, false);
            source_lang = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.sourcelang);
            array_sourcelang = new String[]{"English", "German"};
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter1;
            arrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    simple_spinner_dropdown_item, array_sourcelang);
            source_lang.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);
            target_lang = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.targetlang);
            array_targetlang = new String[]{"English", "German"};
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    simple_spinner_dropdown_item, array_targetlang);
            target_lang.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2);
            return view;
        }

//Errors


 Error:(20, 50) error: incompatible types: View cannot be converted to Spinner
Error:(26, 50) error: incompatible types: View cannot be converted to Spinner
Error:(30, 20) error: cannot find symbol method setAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String>)
Error:(25, 20) error: cannot find symbol method setAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String>)

//my xaml file lang_spinner.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_spinner"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context="com.example.sarimahmed.fyp.Spinner">
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/sourcelang"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:popupBackground="@color/spinnerbackground" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/langswapbtn"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_swap1"
            />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:popupBackground="@color/spinnerbackground"
            android:id="@+id/targetlang"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:textColor="@color/mytextcolor"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Spinner source_lang;
Spinner target_lang; use this

Comment: did it but still getting these errors

Comment: clean build and try running again

Comment: if error are there post

Comment: i tried everything  Error:(20, 50) error: incompatible types: View cannot be converted to Spinner
Error:(26, 50) error: incompatible types: View cannot be converted to Spinner
Error:(30, 20) error: cannot find symbol method setAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String>)
Error:(25, 20) error: cannot find symbol method setAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String>)

Comment: issue is resolved by importing import android.widget.Spinner; thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line.

```
import static android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item;
```

Try this,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_sourcelang);

ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_targetlang);
```

Comment: thnx issue is resolved by import android.widget.Spinner;

Answer (score 2):

> incompatible types: Spinner cannot be converted to String

Because `source_lang` and `target_lang` declared as `String`.

Use `Spinner` instead of `String` when declaring `source_lang` and `target_lang` variables:

```
Spinner source_lang;
Spinner target_lang;
```

Comment: still getting errors                                                                                              Error:(20, 50) error: incompatible types: View cannot be converted to Spinner
Error:(25, 20) error: cannot find symbol method setAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String>)
Error:(26, 50) error: incompatible types: View cannot be converted to Spinner
Error:(30, 20) error: cannot find symbol method setAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String>)

Comment: @SarimAhmed: ok show `lang_spinner` xml file

Comment: ok i have pasted the xml code in question :)

Comment: @SarimAhmed: show  updated code of `lang_spinner` class bez everything is k . try to run code after clean and refresh

Comment: @SarimAhmed: it's good. please show update code of lang_spinner to  check what u  have done

Comment: i have updated the code in question :)

Comment: thank you for help issue is resolved by importing import android.widget.Spinner; i am wondering why android studio did not import automatically or not gave any hint

Comment: @SarimAhmed: Ok see [What is the shortcut to Auto import all in Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615038/what-is-the-shortcut-to-auto-import-all-in-android-studio)

Comment: not any shortcut but it shows hint by pressing alt+enter

Comment: @SarimAhmed: Yes Right :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to change String source_lang; to Spinner source_lang; and String target_lang; to Spinner target_lang;

Comment: did it but still getting these errors