# Java/Android Studio: Import function completes with package name instead of "import..."

Tags: java, android-studio

I am trying to import things in Android Studio. For example, I type *Scanner* and it corrects it to `java.util.scanner` instead of adding `import java.util.Scanner` to the beginning of the file. I would appreciate any help.

[What is the shortcut to Auto import all in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615038/what-is-the-shortcut-to-auto-import-all-in-android-studio) didnt't help me :/

Answer (score 0):

Go to `File -> invalidate caches/ restart`
after that Android Studio will restart itself and you should see the option box when you try to import,
just make sure you are not importing another class from another package but with the same name, that could be a reason too.