# RecyclerView “cannot resolve symbol” errors, - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've created a dummy project to understand Card-Based Layout.
Unfortunately, I am getting cannot resolve symbol errors on RecyclerView.
I'm quite new to programming and can't understand what went wrong.
Dependencies are added to build file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

While I'm trying to create a field in Activity I'm getting cannot resolve symbol errors on RecyclerView.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        RecyclerView recyclerView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Import the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you want to use a class you should import its library.

in this case, you haven't import recyclerview library. to fix this just change your activity code to :

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView; //recyclerview library

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        RecyclerView recyclerView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

- File > Sync Project with Gradle Files

.

Now Remove and start typing the RecyclerView again, it should show up.

Answer (score 0):

You did not import the RecyclerView class, so there's no way your compiler would know what you are talking about. Simply add this line to your import statements:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
```

Your code should run fine after that.

**PS:** 

To make your programming experience easier, you can just auto-import all the classes you need. Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615038/what-is-the-shortcut-to-auto-import-all-in-android-studio) to learn more.

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!