# Do not add unused imports when Java is converted to Kotlin

Tags: android, intellij-idea, kotlin

When I paste some Java code into a Kotlin project, Android Studio can convert the syntax. However, when the converter is invoked, it adds several unused imports to the file, which broke my existing code.

```
import androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.ExtraData
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getSystemService
import android.icu.lang.UCharacter.GraphemeClusterBreak.T
import android.R
```

The pasted code snippet doesn't need these imports. Since I already imported `my.application.R` but AS adds `android.R`, references to `R.` will broke.

Why are these added? Is this a bug in the converter? Can I somehow disable it?

Comment: You can easily use organize imports `Ctrl` + `Atl` + `O` and get rid of them. More on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615038/what-is-the-shortcut-to-auto-import-all-in-android-studio

Comment: Of course I can remove them manually, but it's annoying to do all the time.

Comment: It's likely a code converter bug, try looking it up or reporting at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues.