# Android Developer Guide Contradiction: using nested classes / interfaces differently

Tags: android

I am learning Android apps development. I started by reading the API Guide (I had some background before) and when I came at Layouts section I found the following:

```
// Create a message handling object as an anonymous class.
private OnItemClickListener mMessageClickedHandler = new OnItemClickListener() {

public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Do something in response to the click
    }
};

listView.setOnItemClickListener(mMessageClickedHandler);
```

where:
1- **listView** is a **ListView** object which is subclass of **AdapterView**.
2- **OnItemClickListener** is a nested class (interface) in **AdapterView**.

when I first read that, I noticed it didn't write the anonymous class name as: `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener ...`

I thought that's maybe because it assumes the code is in an AdapterView class, but when I noticed the last line `listView.setOnItemClickListener(mMessageClickedHandler);` I said this must be in an Activity method, I finally concluded that it must be a mistake.

But when I reached Grid View guide (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) and in step no. 4, it writes this snippet:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.main);

GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(HelloGridView.this, "" + position,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     });
  }
```

which also initiate a new class using `OnItemClickListener()` not `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()` , and now it is clearly in "onCreate()" method.

I said to my self maybe it is okay to use it like this because we are putting it as an argument to a method in an object that "OnItemClickListener" is defined in.
(I am an electronics engineer by the way, not specialized programmer, so I thought I missed that when I learnt Java)

**but** when I came to the Toggle Button lesson, I saw this code snippet:
(Link: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html)

```
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
        // The toggle is enabled
    } else {
        // The toggle is disabled
      }
   }
});
```

where it has the same conditions for the previous example, but when it used the nested interface it wrote it with the class containing that interface: `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()` instead of: `OnCheckedChangeListener()` as the previous example.

It has the same conditions of the previous one because:

1- **CompoundButton** and **AdapterView** both contained a nested interface.
2- **ToggleButton** and **GridView** are both subclasses of **CompoundButton** and **AdapterView**, respectively.
3- They are both defined and used in the same scope, i.e. in an activity method.

So, I went to search about the lesson of the GridView to see if someone had problems with it, I found the following question:

[Gridview Tutorial problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276260/gridview-tutorial-problems)

**And he used the same code in the GridView lesson above, and it worked with him!**
(after he imported the appropriate packages)

So why they are used differently? am I missing something in Java? or I had some mistake in what I noticed?

Comment: `new OnItemClickListener()` is perfectly valid, if the developer has `import AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`.

Comment: so does this mean the developer should write `new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()` if `import AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` was not there?

Comment: Correct. That is how you reference nested classes in Java.